# Visual Display of Object Properties - How To

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
var bulk = {
    speed: 0,
    damage: 0,
    type: P,
    statEf: [0],
    health: 0,
    minion: [0],
    pc: 10,
    exp: 9000
}
```

Pretend I want it to show:

- Speed: 0
- Damage: 0
- Type: P
- StatEf: [0]
- Health: 0
- Minion: [0]
- PC: 10
- Exp: 0

I mean, I can make this work via consoles, etc, but I want it to `append` to body, or at least replace (this will be switching).

How would I display the info to the EU?

Comment: Put what you want in a `<ul>` list. What's the problem?

Comment: @barmar - Just loop and `append` to a `ul`? There has to be a quicker method... just researching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ul = $('<ul>');
for (var key in bulk) {
    if (bulk.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        ul.append('<li>' + key + ': ' + bulk[key].toString() + '<li>');
    }
}
$('#someDiv').html(ul);
```

Comment: Here's where you got me [Current Dev](http://sinsysonline.com/havoc/). Just wanted to say thank you, cause I forgot to accept the answer. There is a bug in the checkbox function, but I'm getting there :-)